# Rounding all numbers in a dataframe containing numbers and strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains floats and also strings. I want to round all of the floats to one decimal place.

An example df is depicted below;

```
Y     1      2      3
X
1    5.19   "a"    "a"
2    6.68   6.22   "b"
3    "b"    8.23   8.55
```

Now, I want to round all of the floats by 1 decimal place. My actual dataframe is a lot larger than this, but the strings arr only "a" or "b".

I've tried doing `df[(df != "a") & (df != "b")] = df.round(1)` but this doesn't change anything?

Comment: What is your expected output? Also, is `5.19` a float number or is it a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `pd.to_numeric`

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').round(1).fillna(df)
```

Or:

```
s = df.stack()
pd.to_numeric(s,errors='coerce').round(1).fillna(s).unstack()
```

---

```
Y    1    2    3
X               
1  5.2  "a"  "a"
2  6.7  6.2  "b"
3  "b"  8.2  8.6
```

EDIT per comments:

```
s = df.stack()
s1 = pd.to_numeric(s,errors='coerce').round(1)
s1.astype(str).add('%').mask(s1.isna(),s).unstack()
```

---

```
Y     1     2     3
X                  
1  5.2%   "a"   "a"
2  6.7%  6.2%   "b"
3   "b"  8.2%  8.6%
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me? It just returns zeros and 0.1s?

Comment: Do you know how you could possibly return these as a percentage? So, 5.2%, 6.7% and so on?

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the help.